# How to delete strings that matches a word within the same file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am seeking for a function or script that reads every line and seek for a duplicate or match in the same file to then delete it.

The uniq -u function does half the job. I was trying to use a while read with a grep. Some how it works but for some reason it's outputing twice the strings that it's looking for.

This is the code I have for now to identify the matching word. I did not come up yet with the code to then delete the matching word, but I would have used most likely sed

```
filename=$1
while read line; do
  grep "$line" $filename
done < $filename
```

and this is the file I have

```
JonasB/JB
AZ
LeylaS/LS
JB
AmeliaZ/AZ
```

The expected result should be:

```
JonasB/"JB"
"AZ"
LeylaS/LS
"JB"
AmeliaZ/"AZ"
```

But the result I have is this:

```
JonasB/"JB"
"AZ"
AmeliaZ/"AZ"
"LeylaS/LS"
JonasB/"JB"
"JB"
"AmeliaZ/AZ"
```

The outcome I would like for this script would be:

LeylaS/LS

*Clarification*

The previous example brought some confusion and I apologise for it.

This is other example:

```
ecar/ElectricCar/EV
ElectricCar
EV/ecar
Car/ICE
Van
Hybrid
Truck/Van/MiniVan/BigCar
ElectricVan/ElectricTruck
```

So the FS would be `/`.

The lines 2 and 3 should be deleted, because they match line 1 fields

Line 5 should be deleted with line 7, because it matches the second field

The output I expect to have is:

```
Car/ICE
Hybrid
ElectricVan/ElectricTruck
```

Hope this clarifies better the issue.

Comment: in your `while`loop you are matching `filename` content against itself, probably it is not what you want to do.

Comment: Your question is not fully clear. Does your input file contain quotes (`"`) or not? Do you want to have the output `LeylaS/LS` because there is no line `LS`? If there would be a line `XY` without a corresponding `XabcY/XY` would you want to have a line `XY` in the output? Please [edit] your question for clarification or to add more information.

Comment: So you want to find duplicates or delete them? Hiw do you define a &quot;word&quot;?

Comment: @Bodo Sorry for the confusion, no there are no quotes in the original file. I quoted the to show what grep was matching.
As you said, the LeylaS/LS should be the output because there is no LS or LeylaS in the file. So if either LS or LeylaS match with LeylaS/LS both of those lines needs to be deleted.

Comment: @downtheroad Yeah... I am trying to grep a line in the [filename] and compare it with the whole file. Where it seems in this case I am comparing the lines from filename in the file.

Comment: @KamilCuk Both. So in an other example I want to match the string: ecar/ElectricCar/EV with ElectricCar and then delete both strings

Comment: @Terrenus Please **[edit] your question** to add clarifications instead of answering in comments. Do you want to delete a line like `ecar/ElectricCar/EV` regardless if `ElectricCar` appears before or after it? Is one of the matching lines required to be a single word without `/`? Or would you also delete both lines if there is a line `ecar/ElectricCar` or `ecar/EV` or `somethingElse/ElectricCar`? Is it required to match the whole word, i.e. a line `Car` would not match `ecar/ElectricCar/EV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk instead.

```
BEGIN { FS = "/" } # / is field separator.
($NF in a) {       # if last field is in a;
  delete a[$NF]    # delete it,
  next
} {                # otherwise;
  a[$NF] = $0      # add it to a.
} END {            # at the end;
  for (b in a)     # print everything in a.
    print a[b]
}
```

Invocation:

```
awk -F '/' '($NF in a){delete a[$NF];next} {a[$NF]=$0} END{for(b in a) print a[b]}' file
```

Comment: This worked great for this example. If I want this to work with multiple fields what should I edit?
Example:
JonasB/JB/JonB
JB
AmeliaZ/AZ/AmeZ/ZA
AmeliaZ
AmeZ
And this should delete all entries. Sorry if this goes over the main question.

Comment: @Terrenus actually it does, you should have mentioned about that in your question in first place

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nl -nrz -w6 -s " " "$filename" | sort -k2 | uniq -s7 | sort -n | cut -c8-
```

**nl** numbers the line (6 digits 1 space, max 1 mio lines).
**sort** sorts beginning from part 2 (ignoring line number).
**unique** removes duplicates ignoring 7 chars (the line numbers). **sort** sorts in original order. Finally **cut** removes the line numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately when I tried to run the command, it started duplicating the file multiple times and did not cut the differences.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -nE 'G; /^([[:print:]]+\n)(.+\n)*\1/b; h;P' filename
```